# What is the word for "okay"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I hear a lot of esperantists saying *okay (okej)* but I don't think that is a word. What should people say instead to acknowledge that a statement was heard? For example, should you say *ho* or *nu*?

- John: I am feeling tired today.
- Mark: Okay.

Answer (score 0):

Both *bone* and *okej* are in use. I would suggest that *bone* is more authentically Esperanto, as you said (in different words).

The question was answered here

[What is "OK" in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/what-is-ok-in-esperanto)